# GlassFish - Ошибка 404

Tags: java-ee, glassfish

Добрый день!

Перешел с Tomcat на GlassFish и не могу запустить Hello World на EJB3

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Настройки GlassFish
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Админка GlassFish по адресу 4848 открывается нормально

Но при запуске приложения по тому URL localhost:4848/ActionBazaar/, который указан в конфигурации (на первой картинке) вылетает 404

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На порту 4848 висит консоль администратора Glassfish, сам сервер и развёрнутые на нём приложения доступны на порту 8080. Конкретно это приложение будет доступно по ссылке http://localhost:8080/ActionBazaar/.

Comment: Сергей, большое спасибо, вы правы! Если Вас не затруднит, объясните пожалуйста в двух словах разницу между 4848 и 8080, зачем используется консоль админа (на Томкате вроде через админку можно деплоить проект и еще что-то делать, здесь тот же принцип?) и почему в конфигах IDEA мы пишем именно 4848, а не 8080

Comment: О сетевых портах долго рассказывать, почитайте лучше [тут](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82_(%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8)) и [тут](https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82). Админская консоль используется для управления сервером. Это намного проще, чем редактирование конфигурационных файлов. И разворачивать приложения через неё тоже можно. Для этого в IDEA и прописывается именно 4848.